# autostart keeps resetting

Tags: lxde, lxsession

Im trying to add items to the autostart on desktop launch but the options just keep disappearing.
My file:
.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
currently has:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi

@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi

@xscreensaver -no-splash

@point-rpi
```

But when I add new lines in, such as @firefox-esr and reboot, the autostart file resets to what it had before.

Is there a way to make sure these changes stick?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be using:

```
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I tried that too.

Turns out my sd card was not updating with any changes I made.